# How to move directories within svn

Tags: svn

Currently my project is under foo with 2 sub modules foo/A and foo/B
I have requirement to move A under B, so it looks like this foo/B/A. Is there a clean way to remove SVN references before doing this transition using a svn command.

Comment: This falls within very basic svn usage, please take a look at svn documentation http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
svn mv foo/A foo/B/
```