# Combining repositories in SubVersion

Tags: svn

I know there are posts on this topic, but I haven't found one doing what I'm looking for.

We have this directory structure:

```
SVN
|
-> Project
   |
   -> UI
      |
      -> tag
      -> branch
      -> trunk
   -> Server
      |
      -> tag
      -> branch
      -> trunk
   -> DB
      |
      -> tag
      -> branch
      -> trunk
```

and what I want, whilst maintaining history is:

```
SVN
|
-> Project
   |
   -> trunk
      |
      -> Server
      -> UI
      -> DB
   -> branches
   -> tag
```

So that when I have to make a branch that affects the server, UI and DB I don't have to create 3 individual branches of the same name, one under each sub module (or what ever you'd call it).

We're using SVN 1.7 or later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move directories within svn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346988/how-to-move-directories-within-svn)

Comment: This is *very* basic usage of SVN. Read the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com), in particular the section on [basic editing](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.edit) and the reference for the [svn move](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) command.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a "very basic usage" to me, nor do the two sections you mention seem to give the information I'm needing.  I agree that I can use it to move the directories around, that I was happy with.  It is the merging of what are basically 3 modules into one, keeping all the branch and tag info etc. that I'm not sure about.

Comment: Basically you need to move `DB/trunk` into `Project/trunk/DB`, yes? Is there some problem with using `svn mv /path/to/repo/DB/trunk /path/to/repo/Project/trunk/DB` that I'm missing?

Comment: That is 1 of about 12 moves, and I don't disagree that it would be easy, what I was more concerned about is the fact that 3 branch and 3 tag directories will becomes 1 branch and 1 tag, and they have branches & tags of the same name inside them.  If possible I don't want to lose any of the revision history.  If that wasn't clear I apologise.

Comment: Having sat down and re-investigated this, I don't think I have an issue with the branches.  I'd forgotten that inside each branch there will be UI, Server and DB folders, so their history will be kept in their

Answer (score 0):

The problem about moving that is about you cannot use wildcards like * for moving every single content on tags or branches, so you have to move it one by one. The solution i've made when I have to do this like 1 month ago, is scripting. Creating an script that generates another one. For each line in /svn/project/ui/trunk move it to /svn/project/trunk/ui for example.

It's not hard to do it, if you're still having problems, ask me about. Like Ben said, its all aobut svn mv.